# How should I collapse two tables into one on SELECT?

Tags: mysql

It's hard to summarize this question into one sentence. I have two tables - one of them is updated automatically and regularly by an external feed. The second table has extra information for some of the rows in the second table, identified by an unique key. Here's an example:

```
Table1
    id: int PRIMARY KEY
    channel: varchar(255) UNIQUE KEY
    name: varchar(255) NOT NULL
    verified: tinyint(1) NOT NULL

Table2
    id: int PRIMARY KEY
    channel: varchar(255) UNIQUE KEY
    extra_info: varchar(255)
```

Table1 is the main table. This is the table that is actually being selected. I would like the fields (other than id and channel) from Table2 to be moved to Table1 upon selection, as if all rows in Table2 that exists in Table1 are merged in upon selection.

For example, I want the information in these two tables to end up as JSON output like this

```
[{
    "id": 5,
    "channel": "bkids2",
    "name": "Bkid",
    "verified": true,
    "extra_info": "Some extra information added using Table2"
},
...
]
```

I'm wondering what the fastest way to proceed is. Can I do this **quickly** using SQL syntax? I know some types of queries are very slow, so perhaps it would be faster to just fetch all data in both tables and perform the merging using the server side programming language?

I'm half way assuming the former is the correct answer, in which case: How do I even do this using MySQL? Subqueries? Joins? Union?

I have to admit I don't fully understand how either of these technologies work or how fast/slow they operate, so thanks to anybody who can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Table1.*, IFNULL(Table2.extra_info, 'DefaultValue') as extra_info
FROM Table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2
ON Table1.id = Table2.id
```

Comment: This works almost perfectly, but how to I set the columns from table2 to a default value if a row couldn't be found? For instance if the `extra_info` column couldn't be filled for a table because no matching row was found in table2, then have it set to the string "{}" or a number or something?

Comment: I have edited my answer adding `IFNULL(Table2.extra_info, 'DefaultValue') as extra_info`.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a query to get the desired output.

```
SELECT id, channel, name, verified, extra_info FROM table_1 NATURAL JOIN table_2
```

this query joins both the table and displays the results common between both.
hope this is the answer to your question....

Comment: I am awake. I left for work after asking this question. I will certainly try your suggestion when I get home :-) Could you explain what makes this solution different from @aziz-shaikh's answer? Pros/cons?

Comment: as u can see he is joining the two tables based on a single column those are first columns respectively....
and I am displaying the result based on complete match of the two tables(It is just like denormalization)

Comment: I haven't had the opportunity to try yet. This is for a non profit project that I work on in my free time only

Comment: I've tested this, and it only selects rows where the channel exists in both tables. That's not what I need. I need the entire table1 to be selected regardless of table2, and table2 data merged in where an unique key matches between the two tables

Comment: ya i see i was nt clear abt ur question... but gud answer by @aziz